# Can i find out symbolic link of opened device, when process IRP_MJ_READ?

Tags: windows, driver, windows-kernel, irp

I have driver, that construct and return some data on IRP_MJ_READ request.
I use some symbolic link to open and read device, associated with driver.
The symbolic link is something like `\\DosDevice\\Name1`.

I want to use same device to get another data from same driver.

How can driver determine, which type of data it would return?

I think, if this is some way to use another symbolic link (for example: `\\DosDevice\\Name2`) to the same device for split requests for first type of data and requests for second type?
Else if this another way, to pass some identifying information together with thre IRP_MJ_READ?

Comment: Do you create the device object and symbolic link?  Or filter a system implemented by others?  If the former, you might create multiple device objects, one for each distinct type of functionality you support, and refer different symlinks to different device objects.  Then you know in the device object what data to produce, without discovering the symlink name at read time.

Otherwise, I think your best opportunity for discovering the open name is at the time a handle is opened to the device, not at read time.

Comment: @asynchronos - for what use multiple device objects instead multiple different files on single device object ?

Comment: @RbMm it's just an alternative, possibly more comfortable for device driver developers (not filesystem driver developers) who aren't familiar with file paths relative to their devices, and FILE_OBJECTs.

Comment: @asynchronos this is bad and wrong alternative, need use exactly not empty file names. that somebody not understand very basic concept as file name on device - only private problem

Comment: @RbMm, Many device classes don't support files.  Sounds like you are talking about filesystem or related drivers.

Comment: @asynchronos - no, this is complete mistake. what is "device class" ? really file names is full supported on **any** device

Comment: need clear understand, that if you create device `\Device\MyDevice` - user can open it by name `\Device\MyDevice` or by Name `\Device\MyDevice\SomeName` - where *SomeName*- can be absolute any and containing **any** symbols. object manager pass you `\SomeName` as is on file object. it not parse it. already driver developer free handle `\SomeName` how he like it. this is exactly case when need handle file names

Comment: so my main points **1** we can and need open device with not empty *FileName* and based on this file name different handle request on file. **2** we not need any symbolic links at all. even for win32 api we always can open device by name `"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\MyDevice[\\FileName]"`. **3** and we can use fastio without actual cache support. (for read/write need set not 0 `PrivateCacheMap` on file, for ioctl even this not need)

Comment: Device class: what type/category of device (functionality) we're considering, e.g. block storage, serial bus, display, network interface, audio, hid, printer.  Most of these support no notion of named files.  To an extent this is formalized by system-provided class drivers, documented USB classes, and "setup classes".

Comment: PrivateCacheMap is supposed to be set to a valid pointer by CcInitializeCacheMap, in a file-system driver that uses cache manager.  Setting it to an arbitrary nonzero value in a non-FS driver sounds like a hack, asking for a bugcheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you can not determinate which symbolic links used and are it used at all for open file on your device. and you not need try do this at all. this is wrong way.

when user open file on your device it specify some file name. and you can and must use this name - based on it - return different content on `IRP_MJ_READ`.

say your device named as `\Device\MyDevice`. user can open file, for example, with next names : `"\Device\MyDevice"`, `"\Device\MyDevice\"` `"\Device\MyDevice\Name1"`, `"\Device\MyDevice\Name2"`. as result you, in your `IRP_MJ_CREATE` will be view next FileObject names : `""`, `"\"`,`"\Name1"`,`"\Name2"` and you, base on file name, can associate different context with file object and then use this context in  `IRP_MJ_READ` and another points. also user can pass additional information on create by using *Extended Attributes* (*EA*) and *AllocationSize*

and as general note - for what use symbolic links to device at all ? why not open it direct by name ? and use `IRP_MJ_READ` exist sense only if you can handle this request asynchronous or pass IRP to lower driver. in case, if you always synchronous complete request - much more better use `FastIoRead` handler

---

also instead on handle read request based on file name, you can use parameters: are you using *ByteOffset* now ? if not you can use it for distinguish. if you use *ByteOffset* now, are *Key* parameter in use ? almost sure that no. in this case you can for *Key==0* return some data, for *Key==1*, some another data, and so on. for use Key you need use `NtReadFile` instead of `ReadFile` in user mode.

also you can use IOCTL instead read file for return data, etc. without more knowledge about your driver and it communication with user mode hard say which is better. but formal answer - you can and need use `FileName` for distinguish which data need return on read

Comment: Symbolic links within DosDevices make the device visible to Win32 APIs.

I don't think Fast IO is relevant to most device drivers:
http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=166

"...fast I/O entry points are only called when information about the particular file is being maintained by the cache manager..."

Comment: @asynchronos - you wrong here in both points. 1 device visible for `CreateFileW` without symbolic links. `\\?\globalroot\Device\DeviceName` - let access `Device\DeviceName` - so for waht need additional symbolic link ? 2.) also absolute wrong. cache manager here absolute not related. any device driver developer can easy use fast io if we always complete request synchronous and not call (pass irp) to another driver

Comment: simply for `FastIoRead` need not 0 (by any `PrivateCacheMap` on file). but say for `FastIoDeviceControl` enough have `fastIoDispatch && fastIoDispatch->FastIoDeviceControl` (`PrivateCacheMap` not checked). so for use `DeviceIoControl` enough have `FastIoDeviceControl`. for `ReadFile` need init `PrivateCacheMap`

Comment: Ha, \\?\globalroot works because globalroot is a symbolic link within DosDevices.  What if the user-mode code already exists and doesn't tolerate such paths?  And what if OP wants to enumerate available devices/"files"?  The Win32 API QueryDosDevice() can list the symlinks in DosDevices.  Discovering the contents of \Device requires undocumented native APIs.  And discovering the files within a single device requires the device behave as a file system.

Comment: PrivateCacheMap is "An opaque member, set only by file systems, that points to handle-specific information and that is used for Cache Manager interaction."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @asynchronous - `PrivateCacheMap` is set by call `CcInitializeCacheMap`. and clear by call `CcUninitializeCacheMap`. and used exclusively by cache manager. we can formal call `CcInitializeCacheMap` on `IRP_MJ_CREATE` for set it and `CcUninitializeCacheMap` on cleanup. however, if we really not make any call to Cc we can simply set here any non zero value - `NtReadFile` - simply check it nonzero before use `FastIoRead`. and nobody will be use it, if we by self not call Cc. for `FastIoDeviceControl` we not need even this.

Comment: of course for call `CcInitializeCacheMap` on `FileObject` we must first set `SectionObjectPointer` on it. for formal set it to nonzero - of course nothing need. `NtReadFile` and `NtWriteFile` simply check `PrivateCacheMap` for 0 before try fast io. the `NtDeviceIoControlFile` at all not check `PrivateCacheMap` - as result we always can use `FastIoDeviceControl` instead `IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL` without trick with `PrivateCacheMap`. here question - are we really need `IRP`. if we want asynchronous call or pass this `IRP` to another driver this is one case. if we not need this - can use fastio

Comment: *for call CcInitializeCacheMap on FileObject we must first set SectionObjectPointer on it.* + `FsContext` to allocated `FSRTL_COMMON_FCB_HEADER` forget add(`FsContext2` can be 0). but all this need only in case we real want support Cc on file. but can simply set `PrivateCacheMap=(PVOID)1` and never call *Cc* api on it.

Comment: If possible for the OP, I think your suggestion to use IOCTL (DeviceIoControl) is a good idea.  One device object, one optional symlink, no file names, several custom control codes that can be checked at IO time (rather than CreateFile time) and no hacks.

Comment: @asynchronos - may be. hard to say without knowledge of driver /user mode implementations and requirements. however for use `FastIoDetachDevice` even not need small hack with `PrivateCacheMap`. all what we need here - `static FAST_IO_DISPATCH s_fiod = { sizeof(FAST_IO_DISPATCH), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, FastIoDeviceControl };DriverObject->FastIoDispatch = (PFAST_IO_DISPATCH)&s_fiod;` and `FastIoDeviceControl` will be called on ioctl. not need any cache support here or hacks